# Undefined variable in creating new object error with constructor

Tags: php, oop

I am a 2nd Year IT student just started with OOP in PHP and i'm really struggling to get the hang of it, **I have been coding in a procedural way for years so please understand making the switch to OOP is extremely challenging,** and I am yet to see the benefit of it, anyway just had to get that of my chest.

**Question**
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

According to the above question I came above with the above code,, which I tweaked to infinity, my prescribed book is also not very helpful

**CODE**

```
class Registration{
        private $user_type;
        private $user_name;

        function __construct($user_type, $user_name){
            $this->user_type=$user_type;
            $this->user_name=$user_name;
        }//constructor

        function setUser($user_type, $user_name){
            if($user_type == "admin"){
                $user_name = "Peter";
                $msg = "Hi administrator ".$user_name;  
            }
            else if($user_type="member"){
                $user_name = "Ntubele123!";
                $msg = "Hi member ".$user_name; 
            }
        }//function

        function getUser(){
            return $this->user_type;
        }//function getter

}//class

    $userInfo = new Registration($user_type, $user_name);
        $user = $userInfo->setUser("admin", "Peter");
        $user = $userInfo->getUser();
```

**MY QUESTIONS**

- I suspect a lot is wrong with the above code, *if someone could be kind enough to let me know where I am going wrong and what I should consider changing*, keeping beginner friendly in mind, it would be greatly appreciated.

**ERROR**

Undefined variable user_type & user_name

Comment: before the line starting with `$userInfo = new ...` you need to create the `$user_type` and `$user_name` variables you're passing to `new Registration($user_type, $user_name`.. `$user_type = $user_name = '';` should do

Comment: Your setter method isn't setting anything. It's ignoring the username that's passed in, and always showing greetings for Peter or Ntubele123.

Comment: @Barmar it is showing nothing mate only prints `admin` on screen when initializing the object as `new Registration("admin", "Peter")` aaaarrrrrgggghhhh

Comment: I'm talking about `setUser`, which is supposed to set the user to the name given in the argument, but just displays a message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$userInfo = new Registration($user_type, $user_name);
```

In this line `$user_type`, `$user_name` is undefined because no variables declared with this name

So declare the variable at first than create object of `Registration` class

Comment: Thank you for your help and input....When I do that  by initializing the object as `new Registration("admin", "Peter")` I only get the output `admin` printed on screen....? So clearly some of my methods are wrong? –

Comment: you have to define variable before `$userInfo = new Registration($user_type, $user_name);`

Comment: OK sure but where do I define that variable in one of my methods?

Comment: Tell me what you exactly need. when you want set user?

Comment: I want SetUser to be as follows When `user_type` = `admin` and `user_name` = `peter` I want message displayed `Hi Admin Peter` else I want messaged displayed `Hi member Ntubele123`

Comment: Thanks mate and while it works perfectly and I really appreciate your time and effort it goes against the instructions of the assignment which says you should only declare 2 properties and use 1 getter and setter method.....but again awesome code and thank you for all your effort wish I could make it up for you

Comment: if my solution works for you than make this answer as accepted

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing different about using variables in OOP code. You still have to set them before you can use them as arguments. So it should be:

```
$name = "Fred";
$type = "admin";
$user = new Registration($type, $name);
```

Your setter method is supposed to set the value of the property. So it should be:

```
function setUser($username) {
    $this->user_name = $username;
}
```

A setter method should normally just set one property at a time.

The whole class should then look like:

```
class Registration{
    private $user_type;
    private $user_name;

    function __construct($user_type, $user_name){
        $this->user_type=$user_type;
        $this->user_name=$user_name;
    }//constructor

    function setUser($user_name){
        $this->user_name = $user_name;
    }

    function setType($type) {
        $this->user_type = $type;
    }

    function getUser(){
        return $this->user_name;
    }//function getter

    function getType() {
        return $this->user_type;
    }

    function greet() {
        echo "Hello " . $this->user_type . " " . $this->user_name;
    }

}//class

$user = new Registration("admin", "Joe");
$user->greet();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort and insight